# Equal Padding for Recyclerview with Grid Layout Manager

Tags: android, padding, gridlayoutmanager

My recyclerview xml code is:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/blogrow"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            />
```

and my CardView code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#fff"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/profilePostImage"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I have used gridlayout manager:

```
mgridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2);
        mgridLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
```

The problem is the images that I get has uneven paddings. For example, the left padding for the left column images is less. There is a good amount of padding in between the two columns. And there is a terrible amount of padding in the right of right column images.
How to fix such that the columns will have even paddings?

Comment: give only padding into cardview and remove margin from recyclerview and card view

Comment: Padding in cardview and margin in recyclerview works! Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give each item in the recyclerview same equal height and width you should use `recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)`

Comment: can you explain what is the problem